# Deserializing JSON when type unknown - .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to understand the best way to deserialize Json data coming from a REST API.

One of the endpoints on the API I'm working with will either return a `User` object or an `ApiException` object.

So I have to do

```
var user = JsonConverter.Deserialize<User>(json);
if(user.UserId == 0)
{
    var error = JsonConverter.Deserialize<ApiException>(json);
}
```

or

```
if(!json.Contains("error"))
{
    var user = JsonConverter.Deserialize<User>(json);
}
else
{
    var error = JsonConverter.Deserialize<ApiException>(json);  
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this?

EDIT: I guess another way would be IF the api returned a wrapper class around the response that included what the type was but this still feels clunky for some reason.

Comment: if error ....return ApiException and if not error return User.... the keyword is **return** it helps reduce the if else's

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @RohitKumar but how do I know the response in an error?

Comment: Ideally the endpoint should itself take care of this abstraction....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to use the [JsonDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#use-jsondocument-for-access-to-data) class from System.Text.Json to poke at the raw data before deserializing into either of the possible types. For example, if the presence of a "userId" key is a reliable way to identify as user object, you could test for this in the JsonDocument in a performant manner without needless deserialization of the wrong type. It would look something like:

```
using JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
if (document.RootElement.TryGetProperty("userId", out _))
{
    var user = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(json);
    // Do stuff with user
}
else
{
    var error = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ApiException>(json);
    // Do stuff with error
}
```

To know whether this actually is better than blind deserialization of both types, I'd throw it into a benchmark to see which wins in your case. I did a quick test with a relatively small "User" parsed from a UTF8 byte array. My benchmark results:

```
|           Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |  Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|----------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|-------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|     JSONDocument | 2.500 us | 0.0193 us | 0.0181 us | 0.1297 |     - |     - |     824 B |
|      StringParse | 1.360 us | 0.0096 us | 0.0090 us | 0.2460 |     - |     - |    1544 B |
| BlindDeserialize | 2.084 us | 0.0132 us | 0.0123 us | 0.1335 |     - |     - |     840 B |
```

It appears for this example searching the raw string for "UserId:" is faster than using JSONDocument, but consumes more memory. "BlindDeserialize" is deserialzing both and checking the result. Not scientific in the least, of course, but gives a flavor for alternatives.

Comment: This would be similar to the string search but possibly slower since it would need to parse the object.

Comment: I was curious and did a quick benchmark. Updated answer with result.

Comment: Thanks for the update on this. I had this same issue when working with a websocket api which could return any object since there are no end-points and was much worse than picking between two possible objects. I was hoping there was a better way then big if/else blocks trying or peeking into the data before deserializing but I don't think it's possible since there's no way for the serializer to know what the data is.

Comment: I'd be interested in a more concise way. My current project has a 30+ case switch block for just this reason :).

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. I don't believe the magic bullet I'm hoping for exists but I do like your solution. I'm worrying about readability more than performance with this project so this is a great option.